# Merging Uservoice and Google Analytics CSS into application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Both user voice and google analytics give some small javascript code which internally loads another BIGGER js file from their server during page load. I am looking to reduce the HTTP requests. Can I download these files and let RAils assets precompile merge them into one? Or you think this will cause issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. Both Uservoice and Analytics need to do AJAX requests to the corresponding site.

According to the AJAX cross-domain request policy, they **have** to be on the same domain as the page they're calling. If you'd pack them into your javascript they would break.